# Combining data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, intersection

I have a background in GIS but haven't worked with it in years, and QGIS isn't my strong suit.

[image: Map]

I have two shapefile layers:

- Layer 1 is polygon, for provincial basemap.  I also joined a lot of other data to this basemap based on provincial classification (like 30 fields).
- Layer 2 is point data, approximately half a million or so.

What I am more or less trying to end up with is an exported csv table with fields/attributes from both layers combined, categorized by province of course.  It's not really practical to do this outside of GIS processing for reasons; plus this is a dry run in advance of a similar procedure with much more complicated data.  So this is why I am doing this in QGIS.

My problem is that the intersection tool does not seem to be working well.  It appears to get hung up and I doubt it would ever complete, something seems wrong.  I would prefer to just combine all of the data into a new point data layer and then export that CSV table so I have both, but could compromise with just the CSV table if it is easier to produce.

Is there  an alternative method to using the intersection tool?

Also, I don't know if QGIS has GPU acceleration or if it can be applied to this tool, because that would probably move it along faster, but I suspect it would still be lengthy if it was working at all.

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by location` with the points as the first input, and the provinces as the second?

Comment: What format is this data in? If using a format like geopackage you can use spatial indexes to speed up processing. QGIS does have OpenCL GPU acceleration for certain algorithms https://www.itopen.it/opencl-acceleration-now-available-in-qgis/

Comment: Research "godzilla polygons". You need to partition the *very* detailed ocean boundaries from the point-in-polygon algorithm where possible, and this query would finish in seconds.

Comment: Erik, your answer worked out.

Comment: @BeaverFever please reframe from posting personal comments, can we focus on the question you are asking, thanks. (removed comment)

Comment: Since you mentioned you have two shapefiles, did you press the Create Spatial Index button in Source? Another tip is to split up your data to a smaller region level? Half a million points is quite a lot. If it appears to hang, just have some patience... If you cant split up the data and want to work out half a million points at once, try Python and the Geopandas library. But thats a whole different domain.

Comment: ThomasHaarlem, my project, in fact, is primarily based on deep learning with Python and Pandas.  But I am doing this part specifically in QGIS for many reasons.  Like I said, Erik mentioned the tool that did exactly what I needed to do.  Aside from that, I have no idea why admins here find it necessary to arbitrarily tamper with my posts but that fud mentality is a great reason for me to be hesitant to contribute to this website in the future, which is a real shame but fuds ruin everything just to satisfy their narcissistic sense of self-preservation.